# Using NuGet.PackageManager, How to get Installed packages with dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

### Intro

Using [NuGet.PackageManagement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.PackageManagement) at runtime to enable users to install packages (from a private repo) where the packages will be loaded by `System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext` and executed.

The install method uses a `NuGetPackageManager` and `NuGetProject` that's been setup appropriately from what could understood in `NuGet.Client`

`_nugetProject` is an instance extending `FolderNuGetProject` that stores packages in a specified folder and `GetInstalledPackagesAsync` returns a list of installed packages instead of an empty list.

`_packageManager` is a `NuGetPackageManager` and `_packageRepository` is a `SourceRepositoryProvider`, both are default instances setup with the appropriate paths and source repos.

```
public async Task InstallPackageAsync(string packageId, SemanticVersion packageVersion, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var packageIdentity = new PackageIdentity(packageId, new NuGetVersion(packageVersion.ToNormalizedString()));

        using (var sourceCache = new SourceCacheContext()) {

            var resolutionContext = new ResolutionContext(
                DependencyBehavior.Highest,
                includePrelease: true,
                includeUnlisted: true,
                VersionConstraints.None,
                new GatherCache(),
                sourceCache);

            var projectContext = new EmptyNuGetProjectContext()
            {
                PackageExtractionContext = new PackageExtractionContext(
                        PackageSaveMode.Defaultv3,
                        XmlDocFileSaveMode.Skip,
                        ClientPolicyContext.GetClientPolicy(_nugetSettings, _nugetLogger),
                        _nugetLogger),
                ActionType = NuGetActionType.Install,
            };

            var previewActions = await _packageManager.PreviewInstallPackageAsync(
                _nugetProject,
                packageIdentity,
                resolutionContext,
                projectContext,
                 _packageRepository.GetPrimaryRepositories().ToList(),
                  _packageRepository.GetRepositories().ToList(),
                  cancellationToken);

            // List all actions in debug log.
            var debugOutput = new StringBuilder();
            debugOutput.AppendLine($"Install actions for {packageId}:");
            foreach(var action in previewActions)
                debugOutput.AppendLine($" - {action.NuGetProjectActionType}: {action.PackageIdentity}");

            _logger.LogDebug(debugOutput.ToString());

            await _packageManager.ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync(
                _nugetProject,
                previewActions,
                projectContext,
                sourceCache,
                cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

### Problem

The goal is to get a dependency graph of a specific package that was installed and use that information to load the assembly and it's required dependencies.

The difficulty is not being able to find any relevant API that already exists that would do this. Seeing as this is very common task in Visual Studio, it's been assumed that NuGet would provide a means to build a dependency graph.

There is `await _nugetProject.GetInstalledPackagesAsync(cancellationToken)` However this only returns a list of `PackageReference`s, that only contain the `VersionRange` and `PackageId`.

Note: [NuGet.Client](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client) has served as the reference for how to use NuGet APIs properly

Comment: An alternative is to read each package's `.nuspec` and build the dependency graph from there. Hoping there is an API in NuGet that does that already